# Delphi var parameter setting length from inside of procedure

Tags: delphi

I am trying to pass some strings to an dynamic string array in this case it is working:

```
procedure DoSomeThing(in_cmd: string; var out_strs: array of string);
begin
  ..
  for n := low(out_strs) to high(out_strs) do
    begin
      out_strs[n] :='bla bla';
    end;
end;
```

In application using as:

```
.
.
.
SetLength(my_out_str, sizer);

DoSomeThing('do it now', my_out_str);
.
.
```

But I want to **SetLength** of **my_out_str** from in the procedure.
Is it possible?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140387  This is a known gotcha, its roots are in very very very old days when Pascal (not even Delphi yet) did not had dynamic arrays at all...

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to declare the parameter with a previously defined dynamic array type.  you are currently using an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters) instead.

```
type
  TStrDynArray = array of string;

procedure DoSomeThing(in_cmd:string; var out_strs: TStrDynArray);
begin
  SetLength(out_strs, 2 * Length(inn_cmd));
  ...
```

Or, use `TArray<string>` if generics are available (from Delphi 2009)

```
procedure DoSomeThing(in_cmd:string; var out_strs: TArray<string>);
begin
  SetLength(out_strs, 2 * Length(inn_cmd));
```

The reason for this is that `array of x` in one context is not the same as `array of x` in another context.

**In a type declaration**

```
type
  TDynamicArray = array of string;
```

Is a dynamic array type, which can be resized.  Dynamic arrays were introduced in Delphi 4.

**In a parameter definition**

```
procedure Test(var X: array of string);
```

Is an [open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Open_Array_Parameters) which means that it will accept arrays of different sizes as input. It just takes a pointer (i.e. reference) to the first element, and the index of the last element in the array. It does not know or care whether the input array is a dynamic array or a static array, and thus will not allow the length to be resized.

Open array parameters predate Delphi 1.

**Further reading**
http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the article. <g>